# Laravel: Converting m/d/Y to Y-m-d from jQuery UI Datepicker before saving to database

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to save a date from jQuery UI datepicker to database.

I want to display the date in m/d/Y format on date selection from the input form.

When I try to save it to the database, it is giving the following error:
**SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value**

I have followed a lot of solutions, however it is not working for me.

I have looked through this [link](https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-change-date-format-in-laravel-and-jquery-ui-datepicker/), though I followed everything correctly, it is still returning the same error.

**Controller Code**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Frontend::create($request->all());
    }
```

**Model Code**

```
class Frontend extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'frontend';

    protected $fillable = ['date'];

    public function setDateAtttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat($date)->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

**config>app.php**

```
'date_format' => 'm/d/Y',
'date_format_javascript' => 'mm/dd/yy',
```

I am new to this and it would be a huge help if anyone could help me find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change under **setDateAtttribute()**
`public function setDateAtttribute($date) { $this->attributes['date'] =  Carbon::parse($date); }`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this method

```
$this->attributes['date'] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, Carbons createFromFormat method take 2 arguments.
`Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time)`

If you define $dates property on your model like:

```
class Frontend extends Model {

    protected $dates = [
        'date',
    ];
}
```

Then you dont have to worry about formatting, you just pass a Carbon instance to
`$date` property. Eloquent should automatically save in correct format. Plus when any record is retrieved, your `$date` will be Carbon instance as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked using your solution combining it with the solution provided by Malik Waqas.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one specific for your js code :

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
   dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
});
```